# Flattening a complex object hierarchy so I can data bind to it in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, graphics

I wrote a molecular display component in WPF.  I used an MVVM architecture data binding to bind atom and bond shapes to an underlying hierarchical data model.
[image: Insulin Molecule]
The model can sometimes consist of nested **Molecule** objects, each of which contains **Atom** and **Bond** objects.  It works well, but I have to flatten the hierarchy of molecules, and the collections of **Atoms** and **Bonds**, to data bind the View to them.  In this display you are looking at a three-level deep hierarchy.  The top level is one **Molecule**, which contains two nested **Molecules**, each of which contain two separate **Molecules** [image: Nested molecule]

This is very difficult to program against and hits performance.  As I have used a generic **ItemsControl** and simply replaced the **ItemsPanelTemplate** with a **Canvas**,  I was wondering if it is possible to customize a **TreeView** by replacing its **ItemsPanelTemplate** with a **Canvas**, and then using a **HierarchicalDataTemplate** to place each **Atom** and **Bond** on the **Canvas**.

My question is therefore:  will this create a separate **Canvas** for each level of nesting?  I *don't* want this.  I want all objects to be positioned on the *same* **Canvas** and for the user to be unaware of the nesting unless I want them to be.

Comment: I think the trick here is proper MVVM with type targetting data templates: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview#the-datatype-property You can of course have tree structures or recusive data templaes. However I am uncertain if that is a easy to do example at all. Molecular diagrams are not usually displayed with GUI technology. Usually some game-like direct drawing like in CAD programms is used.

Comment: Thanks, but direct drawing is an awful lot of work, and WPF has certain facilities such as adorners that make highlight and selecting of components much easier.

You're right in that it is not an easy example!

Comment: I eventually abandoned data binding to generate the shapes.  The chemistry is now represented by DrawingVisuals.  Much, much quicker and actually easier to program.

Comment: It is good to know that my instincts regarding "not the right case for GUi technology" are still sharp.

Comment: It worked well enough to get the thing out the door.  Now it works better.